# How to deal with a manager that keeps forgetting but refuse to admits it

Tags: manager

I have a manager that like to be informed on everything I do to a absurd degree. With I have tried to comply with, taking a few minute to explain everything I'm planing to before i do it. The problem is that he keeps forgetting what I have explain. So when I'm done with something he usually ask why I didn't tell him before I did it what I was going to do. I have tried on several occasions to explain that I did explain what I was going to do but he probably just forgot. But that just lead to that he get angry and debate heatedly that I have not explained. I have tried sending the information by email instead but then I hear comments like i haven't gotten that email. And the same story again.

I know for a fact that he just sleeps a few hours each night and that is probably why he keep forgetting. It just seems like a waste of time explain what I'm going to do if he will immediately forget what I told him.

Comment: Show him the email in your sent folder and ask him to search for it on his side if it's such a big deal.  In addition, if you REALLY want to get him off your back, send him an email whenever you do ANYTHING for a given project, just so you're constantly at the top of his inbox.  He'll either get fed up, or this will be enough to keep him satisfied.  Either way, it's a good way to cover your butt.

Comment: Document everything.  As was said send him a email and copy yourself.  Cover youself.

Comment: Keep a notepad.  Before and after approaching the boss keep a written record of what was said.  When he asks you to re-explain flip back in your notepad and say "We had this discussion on such and such a date..."  Having a written record will help you sleep because the ideas are not bouncing around in your head at night.

Comment: These comments seem like a good start to an answer ;)

Comment: I think the answer is simple: he's an idiot that has an attention trouble (its not really rare).  The email problem is just an excuse, a bad one for a business email.  Advice : cover yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Get it in writing**

Whether it is a customer, owner, or manager, getting things in writing is the way to go.  As discussed in the comments email is a go to method for this.  You maintain a copy of the sent email in your sent box and so if it is ever challenged you have proof to back it up.

If that proves not to be enough you can resort to turning on read receipts on emails you send to your manager.  Which in theory at least you will get an email if your manager opens the email which would be further proof that they cannot deny knowing what you are up to.  I say in theory because some people have their inbox configured to never send read receipts and your manager may never bother to open up your email in the first place.  Also, this has the potential to annoy your manager if they have their inbox configured to prompt.

Comment: The OP may have to include in the email, that he will not proceed until the boss responds with approval. Otherwise, the idiot boss will continue to say he didn't get it.